# Text not getting displayed on screen in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was making a Pong game in pygame where I had this function which sets the ball to center and waits for 2-3 secs when player or opponent has scored a goal

When the ball shifts to center and waits for 2-3 secs , I added a timer  `self.score_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()` which will get initialised when the goal was made .

In ball_start(), I am taking current time and checking the duration and respectively displaying 3, 2, 1.

The function is working fine for shifting ball to center and stopping for 2-3 secs but this 3, 2, 1 text is not getting displayed on the screen.

font and color used

```py
self.light_grey = (200, 200, 200)
self.game_font = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 50)
```

function code :

```py
    # when player or opponent scores, shift ball to center and randomise its initial direction
    def ball_start(self):
        self.ball.center = (self.screen_width / 2, self.screen_height / 2)

        # checking  after goal is scored if 2-3 secs are passed or not
        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        # 3
        if current_time - self.score_time < 800:
            num_3 = self.game_font.render("3", False, self.light_grey)
            self.screen.blit(num_3, (self.screen_width / 2 - 10, self.screen_height / 2 + 20))

        # 2
        if current_time - self.score_time < 1600:
            num_2 = self.game_font.render("2", False, self.light_grey)
            self.screen.blit(num_2, (self.screen_width / 2 - 10, self.screen_height / 2 + 20))

        # 1
        if current_time - self.score_time < 2400:
            num_1 = self.game_font.render("1", False, self.light_grey)
            self.screen.blit(num_1, (self.screen_width / 2 - 10, self.screen_height / 2 + 20))

        if current_time - self.score_time < 2400:
            # making speeds 0 so ball won't move
            self.ball_x_speed = 0
            self.ball_y_speed = 0
        else:
            # if 2-3 secs are passed make ball move
            self.ball_x_speed = 8 * random.choice((1, -1))
            self.ball_y_speed = 8 * random.choice((1, -1))
            self.score_time = None
```

Comment: If you add `print` statements next to the `blits` inside the `if` statements, do they output? e.g. do the `if` statments get called correclty? I don't think the problem is in the code you posted. Please try to create a (somewhat) complete example that we can execute and see the problem.

Comment: Yes, it is printing anything which is written after blit() .
Here's the full code : https://github.com/Patrickbro13/PongPygame
let me know if you found the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Expected, the problem is not inside the code you were showing.

In you main loop, this is the rending order you have:

```
    if pong.score_time:
        pong.ball_start()
    pong.ball_animation()
    pong.player_animation()
    pong.opponent_animation()
    pong.draw_objects()
```

This means that everything futher down in the list will override what comes before.

Most notably, `ball_start` is in the bottom. This might no be a big problem, but it is, because you background fill is in `draw_objects`, which comes after `ball_start`.

To fix, just move `ball_start` after `draw_objects`, or (even better IMO), move the background fill directly into the main loop.

```
    pong.ball_animation()
    pong.player_animation()
    pong.opponent_animation()
    pong.draw_objects()
    if pong.score_time:
        pong.ball_start()
```

Comment: Yes yes, I understood what is happening from your explanation and code is working now . Thanks !